# Reroute an user event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I've got a component with a custom `OnTap` handler and I don't want this method to be public.

My problem is that I've got another component layered on the first one, so the latter will intercept every `Tap` event.

I know that I can just make the first method public and call it from the `OnTap` event of the second component, but I'm looking for a way to avoid this and just "reroute" the tap event to the other component.

Is this possible?

I can't find anything online!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a public event in your object and have other objects subscribe to it. When `OnTap` happens raise your own event.

```
public event EventArgs RouteEvent;
```

**OR**

```
public event Action<EventArgs> RouteEvent;
```

Comment: So there's no way to reroute the event or to simulate a "click-through"?

Comment: How is what I said not rerouting the event?

Comment: You can also use `Action` to reroute your `OnTap` event.